# Calculating with Java Input/Output - decimals

Tags: java, java-io

I'm trying to create a calculator that calculates decimal numbers by taking input from the user. I'm trying to add the two values. My code is the following below:

```
import java.io.*;
public class calc{
    public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception{
        System.out.println("Input 1st no");
        InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
        BufferedReader p=new BufferedReader(reader);
        String k = p.readLine();
        float a= (float) k;
        System.out.println("Enter 2nd no");
        InputStreamReader read = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
        BufferedReader l = new BufferedReader(read);
        String z = l.readLine();
        float b = (float) z;
        float res = (b+a);
        System.out.println("Final result is: " +res);
    }
}
```

So what should have been the fix to this? I've tried compiling with no luck. It gives the error "Incompatible types" and I do know it is incompatible but I don't think so there is any other method to detect decimal numbers.

Comment: By convention the class should start with an upper case letter; Calc. You should also post the compiler output so we can easier see which line is failing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't simply do `float a= (float) k;` to cast from `String` to `float`.

You should call the `Float.parseFloat(k)` instead.

Note that this function could throw a `NumberFormatException` if the string does not contain a parsable float.

Answer (score 1):

You got quite far.

This should do it:

```
    float a = Float.valueOf(k);
```

and

```
    float b = Float.valueOf(z);
```

If I may offer some hints, firstly, name your class `Calc` rather than `calc` :)

Maybe consider using `double` over `float` (due to precision issues).

And use more meaninful (longer) variable names (google `camel-case`).

Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

The method `readLine()` returns `String`. You can't cast `String` to `float` directly. 
You can do `Float f = Float.valueOf(k)`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot cast types like this:

```
 String z = l.readLine();
 float b = (float) z;
```

To convert a String to a Float use

```
Float b = Float.parseFloat(z);
```